# Undefined reference to winsock when using crypto library

Tags: c, ssl, cryptography, winsock

I have a program that worked fine using winsock in c.
I've trked to add ssl to the program, however am getting errors such as

```
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c|| undefined reference to `shutdown@8'|
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c|| undefined reference to `shutdown@8'|
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c|| undefined reference to `WSASetLastError@4'|
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c|| undefined reference to `recv@16'|
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c|| undefined reference to `WSASetLastError@4'|
```

as if libcrypto can't find the winsock functions. The winsock2 is linked and the program compiles fine without the crypto library.

I am using code::blocks and have the following:

```
-lws2_32
-lssl
-lcrypto

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

I can't figure out why i am getting these linking errors, please help!

Comment: Not sure whether gcc on Windows cares about case of file names but the winsock library should be `Ws2_32.lib`

Comment: thanks adding -lwsock32, -libeay32 and -ssleay32 fixed the compile errors.
The case isn't important in gcc compiler